# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'test' to data type int sql error

Tags: sql, sql-server

im having the error above with the code below. what do i need to fix?

```
SELECT  
ClientName = client.firstname+' '+ client.lastname
stage =
    case 
    when bills.stage=1 then 'test1' 
    when bills.stage=2 then 'test2' 
    when bills.stage=3 then 'test3' 
    end,
FROM client inner join bills on client.id=bills.clientid 
WHERE tbills.stage in (1,2,3)`
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  It is not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: You are missing a comma before state

Comment: Besides the typos already pointed out, I suspect `bills.stage` is not an integer column but an (n)varchar. Try `bills.stage='1'` etc

Answer (score 0):

can you try -  (removed extra comma before from)
`SELECT ClientName = client.firstname+' '+ client.lastname stage = case when bills.stage=1 then 'test1' when bills.stage=2 then 'test2' when bills.stage=3 then 'test3' end  FROM client inner join bills on client.id=bills.clientid WHERE tbills.stage in (1,2,3)`

Answer (score 0):

```
Just tweak a little.

SELECT
  ClientName = client.firstname+' '+ client.lastname,
  stage = 
    case when bills.stage=1 then 'test1'
    when bills.stage=2 then 'test2' 
    when bills.stage=3 then 'test3' end 
FROM 
  client inner join bills on client.id=bills.clientid 
WHERE bills.stage in (1,2,3)
```